# for-loop to cover range increasing/decreasing based on sign of step

Tags: c#, for-loop

How would I modify this for-loop so that it counts up for positive values of `Step`, but counts down for negative values of `Step`?

For `Step = 2`, the expected output is `2 4 6 8 10`

For `Step =- 2`, the expected output is `10 8 6 4 2`

```
// assume these 3 come from user input
int Lower = 2;
int Upper = 10;
int Step = 2;

for ( int i = Lower; i <= Upper; i += Step )
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: How do you detect if the user wants to add or retract?

You can easily go for keeping an integer in a variable and just counting it?
But if a user inputs '2' and you should magically know if it is add or retract that will become a challenge.

Comment: Your code would become to look overcomplicated if you restricted it to a simple for loop. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: If your computation within the loop does not depend on the correct order you could just iterate positivly and reverse the result at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just obey the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

You can just put the logic into the initialiser and the condition of the [`for` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for):

```
public static void ForLoopWithDirectionBasedOnStep(int minValue, int maxValue, int step)
{
    // Avoid obvious hang
    if ( step == 0 )
        throw new ArgumentException("step cannot be zero");

    //  ( initialiser                           ; condition                     ; iterator  )
    for ( int i = step > 0 ? minValue : maxValue; minValue <= i && i <= maxValue; i += step )
        Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

so:

- `ForLoopWithDirectionBasedOnStep(minValue: 2, maxValue: 10, step: 2)` returns:

  ```
  2 4 6 8 10
  ```
- `ForLoopWithDirectionBasedOnStep(minValue: 2, maxValue: 10, step: -2)` returns:

  ```
  10 8 6 4 2
  ```

as desired.

---

The initialiser sets the start value

```
int i = step > 0 ? minValue : maxValue;
```

by using the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and is equivalent to

```
int i;
if ( step > 0 )
    i = minValue;
else
    i = maxValue;
```

---

The condition

```
minValue <= i && i <= maxValue
```

simply checks that the loop variable is within the range [minValue, maxValue].

---

Note that bad inputs are handled automatically because (emphasis mine):

> The condition section, if present, must be a boolean expression. **That expression is evaluated before every loop iteration.**

so something like `ForLoopWithDirectionBasedOnStep(minValue: 10, maxValue: 0, step: -2)` which would count down from `0` to `10` doesn't print anything because, since 0 < 10, the body of the `for` statement is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need a pre-processing step to change the comparison in the for loop as well as its limits

```
int Lower = 2;
int Upper = 10;
int Step = -2;
Func<int, bool> comparator = (j) => j <= Upper;


if (Step < 0)
{
    var temp = Lower;
    Lower = Upper;
    Upper = temp;
    comparator = (j) => j >= Upper;
}


for(int i=Lower; comparator(i); i+=Step)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/icEs4I)

Answer (score 1):

You can do two for loops based on the sign of the `step` variable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int lower = 2;
      int upper = 10;
      int step = -2;

      if (Math.Sign(step) == 1)
      {
        for (int i = step; i < upper; i += step)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", i));
        }
      }
      else if (Math.Sign(step) == -1)
      {
        for (int i = upper; i >= lower; i += step)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", i));
        }
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Crystal clear. I'd add a clause to check when "step" is zero (just in case), otherwise the loop would hang.

Comment: @MarioVernari I updated the code adding an else if statement with the -1. Now if the step is 0 nothing happen and the for loop is not executed. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this code is untested but the idea is to use a `Predicate<T>` for the loop and switching Upper and Lower if step is negative

```
// assume these 3 come from user input
int Lower = 2;
int Upper = 10;
int Step = 2;
if(step < 0){ int temp = Lower; Lower = Upper; Upper = temp;}
Predicate<int> LoopPred = (i =>
{
  if(Step < 0)
    return i >= Upper;
  return i <= Upper;
})


for(int i=Lower; LoopPred(i); i+=Step)
{
    Console.Write(i + “ “);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can make a Func delegate to check if the step is negative and invert the bound checking condition.**

Here's a sample:

---

```
class Program
{
    public static void Print(int Lower, int Upper, int Step)
    {
        Func<int, bool> checkBounds = (i) => i <= Upper;

        if (Step < 0)
        {
            Swap(ref Lower, ref Upper);
            checkBounds = (i) => i >= Upper;
        }

        for (int i = Lower; checkBounds(i); i += Step)
            Console.Write($"{i} ");
    }

    public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
    {
        T temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // assume these 3 come from user input
        int Lower = 2;
        int Upper = 10;
        int Step = -2;

        Print(Lower, Upper, Step);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=Step>0?Lower:Upper; Step>0? i<=Upper: i>= Lower; i+=Step)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

@john All you need to update the looping conditions.